# В библиотеке react-yandex-maps не могу использовать geocode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В событии onLoad пишет: ymaps.geocode is not a function.

```
<YMaps
  query={{
    ns: "use-load-option",
    apikey: "...",
  }}
>
  <Map
    onLoad={(ymaps) => {
      console.log('ymaps', ymaps.geocode);
    } }
    onClick={ onMapClick }
    state={{
      controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl'],
      center: [55.75, 37.57],
      zoom: 9,
    }}
    modules={ ['control.ZoomControl', 'control.FullscreenControl'] }
  >
    <Placemark
      geometry={ placemarkPos } 
      properties={{
        balloonContentBody: 'ballon text......',
      }}
      modules={['geoObject.addon.balloon']}
      options={ { iconColor: 'gold' } }
    />
  </Map>
</YMaps>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
<YMaps query={{ load: "package.full" }}>
```